# Change jena-fuseki logging level

Tags: java, log4j2, jena

There's quite little information on jena-fuseki logging on apache documentation, found just this: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-logging.html

My jena-fuseki in running in rkt-container, started by command

```
./fuseki-server ...
```

I need to change the logging level from INFO to at least WARN or perhaps ERROR.
I tried on test server (i.e. outside of rkt-container) by changing all occurrences of "INFO" to "WARN" 1st in file `<directory of fuseki-server>/webapp/log4j2.properties` and then in file `<directory of fuseki-server>/log4j2.properties` without help.

So, how should I change the logging level ?

Comment: Change the file `log4j2.properties` in $FUSEKI_HOME in the container. Otherwise please say which version you are using and show the start of the logging output.

Comment: @AndyS Thanks, $FUSEKI_HOME was nout defined, but it was enough to change all occurrences of INFO to WARN in <directory of fuseki-server>/log4j2.properties-file with apache-jena-fuseki 3.17.